# How can I access values from select() in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

How can I access values which are return from `select()`. I want all the ids from all linked tables. I'm passing `categoryMaster_id` as a parameter and from that I need remaining ids.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$categoryMaster= (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id,categoryMaster_name,categoryMaster_image,
    productType.productType_id,productType.productType_type,
    product.product_id,product.product_name,product.product_description,
    productQuantity.productQuantity_id,productQuantity.productQuantity_name,productQuantity.productQuantity')
    ->from('categoryMaster')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','productType', 'productType.categoryMaster_id = categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','product','product.productType_id = productType.productType_id')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','productQuantity','productQuantity.product_id = product.product_id')
    ->where('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id', ['categoryMaster_id' => $_GET['categoryMaster_id']])
    ->all();   
    $data['categoryMaster']= $categoryMaster;
```

Comment: so you want the result of the query to be copied to the `$data['categoryMaster']` ? so that you can use it further like arrays

Comment: It's already there,                    {
                "categoryMaster_id": "1",
                "categoryMaster_name": "Dairy",
                "categoryMaster_image": "Dairy_1534931165.jpg",
                "productType_id": "2",
                "productType_type": "Dahi",
                "product_id": "4",
                "product_name": "",
                "product_description": "MILK MILK MILK COW COW COW",
                "productQuantity_id": 1,
                "productQuantity_name": 2,
                "productQuantity": 5
            }

Comment: so what you are trying to acomplish

Comment: you are already selecting the id's from the linked table what resultset do you get

Comment: but i want to use those ids some other places also. how can i access them

Comment: ok, so if i get you correctly, as you are using `->all()` the resultset would have an array of rows returned. and you can access them using `foreach($data['categoryMaster'] as $result){echo $result->name;}` or `echo $data['categoryMaster'][0]->categoryMaster_id;` to display the first and so on, but the recommended way is to use the `foreach`

Comment: You want all `categoryMaster_id` from your query result?

Answer (score 0):

with the query you have a collection of models that you store in the array  `$data`

```
$data['categoryMaster']= $categoryMaster;
```

You can iterate over the array for retrive each model and access to the selected  columns

```
  <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value){
      echo "Key : ".$key. "<br />";
      echo $value->categoryMaster_id ."<br />";
      echo $value->categoryMaster_name ."<br />"
      .....
      echo $value->productQuantity ."<br />"

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail) if you're using custom columns in select - query will return result as array instead of object.

To extract specified filed from result you may use [`ArrayHelper::getColumn()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#getColumn()-detail):

```
$result = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id,categoryMaster_name,categoryMaster_image,
        productType.productType_id,productType.productType_type,
        product.product_id,product.product_name,product.product_description,
        productQuantity.productQuantity_id,productQuantity.productQuantity_name,productQuantity.productQuantity')
    ->from('categoryMaster')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','productType', 'productType.categoryMaster_id = categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','product','product.productType_id = productType.productType_id')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','productQuantity','productQuantity.product_id = product.product_id')
    ->where('categoryMaster.categoryMaster_id=:categoryMaster_id', ['categoryMaster_id' => $_GET['categoryMaster_id']])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();  

$categoryMasterIds = ArrayHelper::getColumn($result, 'categoryMaster_id');
$productTypeIds = ArrayHelper::getColumn($result, 'productType_id');
```

Or use closure to extract touple:

```
$productTypes = ArrayHelper::getColumn($result, function ($data) {
    return [
        'productType_id' => $data['productType_id'],
        'productType_type' => $data['productType_type'],
    ];
});
```